# Referencing sp.runtime.js and sp.js in web parts

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I am trying to create two script editor web parts in SharePoint 2013. Both of them should retrieve items from distinct lists and display them on a page.

In the script editors I am using JavaScript as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/Ventas/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 ...
</script>
```

My trouble is, if there is only one web part,  I see the items of a list. But if I have another script editor like the script above, I get JavaScript errors and no items are displayed. It seems that I cannot reference `sp.runtime.js` and `sp.js` twice.

What is the best practice to use `sp.runtime.js` and `sp.js` in web parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to reference SharePoint JavaScript libraries explicitly, especially in web parts. Consider the [SP.SOD.executeFunc method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff409592.aspx) to *load on demand scripts* instead, for example:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){

   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   //your code goes here...

});
```

Comment: I have done as Vandim has mentioned. when I save my page one of the webparts is not showing up. And when I try to debug it, I get the error SCRIPT5022: The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested. 
sp.js?rev=PaF2ZrI2GlTO1B5ru0gYug%3D%3D, line 2 character 219913but. Please help me on this one. Many thanks

Comment: Ok I have got the issue fixed. I am so embarrassed, that is not even funny. But out of respect for Vadim and our members this is what was wrong. I had copied and pasted the first webpart's javascript to the other webpart. Then made the necessary changes to retrieve the other list. Well I kinda skipped changing the listname... ooops. So when it was looking for items in the other list it threw the error. Will never happen again. Thank you.